# Getting a triangular tear effect in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I want to create a "tear" effect with regular triangular shapes to show I'm omitting part of the middle of a screenshot, something like:

[image: Jagged triangular tear in solid black]

When I search for tear effects all I find is realistic ripped paper edge effect. Anyone know terminology or Gimp instructions referring to this simpler geometric effect I'm looking for?

Comment: The technical term for that effect is ***indenture***, but that isn't going to make searching easy, I'm afraid. (The first eleventy thousand results pages will be about semi-voluntary enslavement contracts, a surprisingly large number of which concern *gimps*.) You might have better luck with ***pinking*** (as in *pinking shears*, used to prevent fraying on cut fabric edges); several search results looked promising, but I don't know whether or not they'd meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a sawtooth pattern. You can make it by rotating a square 45 degrees then making a pattern out of that:

[How to create a "zig zagged, jagged" effect with Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/how-to-create-a-zig-zagged-jagged-effect-with-photoshop)

The one in your example is made with several different sized squares, but the principle is the same. Good luck!

Comment: The squares are different sizes because I freehanded it to illustrate what I was looking for. I thought to rotate squares, but then couldn't remember how to copy+offset+union selections in Gimp. Would be great to have a premade macro where I could just dial in the sawtooth size, though.

Answer (score 1):

On GIMP 2.8 it was a simple matter of creating a new rectangular brush (on the brushes dialog, click on the `new` button) setting the rotation angle (on the tool options) and the spacing (on the brush) itself to suitable values, and draw a staright line (click on first dot, hold shift, click on destination dot).

My settings, and my result:

[image: tool options settings for paintbrush][image: brush settings]

[image: final result]